# Having trouble with `convert` command when destination is missing sub directories

Tags: bash, convert

I have a directory called `src` full of sub directories and other images.  I tried to use one bash statement to automatically resize them all to another destination directory called `thumb` like this:

```
find ./src -type f -follow -iname '*.jp*g' -exec convert -resize 150x150x "{}" "./thumb/${size}/{}" \;
```

This didn't work because the `thumb` directory is initially empty and doesn't have the same directory structure as `src`.

I tried to look up the `man convert` but I can't seem to find the option to automatically make the directories on `convert`.   What's an effective way to convert all my images into a thumbnail size in the `thumb` directory?  Do I need pre-create all the sub directories in thumb?

---

EDIT

I preceded the command above with this:

```
find ./src -type d -follow -exec mkdir -p "thumb/${size}/{}" \;
```

But I'm curious if I'd be able to do everything with one command instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX philosophy is to have commands, which do one thing and one thing only. Commands that can write to a file instead of **stdout** are already stretching this rule.

Whether you can do everything in one command depends on you definition. Does this:

```
find ./src -type f -follow -iname '*.jp*g' -exec /bin/sh -c \
'mkdir -p `dirname "thumb/'${size}'/{}"` &&'\
'convert -resize 150x150x "{}" "./thumb/'${size}'/{}' \;
```

count as one command or several: `find`, `sh`, `mkdir`, `dirname`, `convert`? The line breaks are just for *“readability”*.